# Authenticate users against Active Directory, but require username and password to be inputted

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, active-directory, forms-authentication

I know that this question has been answered before on a pretty high level.

I need to know **how to implement this assuming I am a beginner**.

Is there some tutorial that explains this from beginning to end?

What I would like to do is using MVC 4, c#,  with windows 2008 server,

I would like to prompt for windows user name and password and authenticate the supplied credentials. Depending on the users permissions I want to either allow or disallow read/update/delete. **I do not want to use integrated security.**
Thanks.

Comment: Could you elaborate as to why you don't want to use integrated security?

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial seems to cover what you want:

http://derans.blogspot.co.uk/2010/02/authentication-with-active-directory.html

Try this, and then ask any *specific* questions you have back here. You'll tend to get better answers for more targeted / specific problems.

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful but still doesn't give the whole picture and I still couldn't get it to work. I really need to see the whole project to see where everything goes.